# SELECT DISTINCT vs Java Set/List

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot

I need to get the distinct values from a  column (which is not indexed) and the table contains billions of rows.

So when I use distinct in the select query, the query gets time out as the timeout is set to 3 minutes.

Will be it a good approach to get all the data from the table and then using set we can get the unique values?

please suggest the best approach here.

Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: Can't you create an index?

Comment: How many distinct values are there?

Comment: the scenario is like I need to get unique values from almost all the columns. so its not possible to create index for all the columns i guess.

Comment: around 1 million distinct values

Comment: Most Big-data based solutions are good fit for these kind of requirement -- e.g. apache spark. I think without index in underlying table, you might face issues

Comment: Why can't you put an index on each column?

Comment: not sure if we can create index for each column. If we can thats good to know.
But the problem is we dont own or manage those databases.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to take all rows (especially if there are billions of them), because it is not memory efficient, or you"ll get **OutOfMemoryError**.

The best of course is to rearrange unstructured data.
Also, for big sets of data common practice is to use a **paging (pagination)** mechanism, that allows you to take the data in small chunks, so you'll bypass this timeout issue.

Comment: you mean pagination with the distinct query ?

Comment: Yes. If you are using spring-data repositories, you need to add **Pageable** parameter. If you writing an SQL request, you can use **LIMIT** keyword to achieve the same thing.

Comment: As long as you are reading using a ResultSet rather than a JPA repository which returns a List (or similar), you can read the entire billions of rows without using much memory for the query results themselves. There is no need to use LIMIT.